# How to improve has_one association activerecord queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've a biography model, and it has one to one association with lifestyle model, one with education model, and one to one with location model.

When application loads I need to get all of this information.  I'm doing this by:

```
biography = current_user.biography
lifestyle = biography.lifestyle
education = biography.education
location = biography.location

result = { "biography" => biography, "lifestyle" => lifestyle, "education" => education, "location" => location}
```

And then sending the json result back:

```
render :json => result
```

So I'm executing total of four queries for this get.  Is there a way to issue less queries and get the same result back?

I've tried using joins, but it is only returning columns from one table.
n+1 won't really help here as I'm not looping over the results.
Also, includes hasn't given me the desired results also.

Is there a better alternative?

Here are some of the associations:

```
class Lifestyle < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :biography
end

class Biography < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :lifestyle, dependent: :destroy
   has_one :education, dependent: :destroy
   has_one :location, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Comment: You say it has associations, are these associations actually defined in the models? Please show more of your actual code.

Comment: Yes these are associations defined in model with has_one, and belongs_to.  Biography has_one lifestyle, has_one education, and has_one location.  And all three belongs_to biogrpahy.  I'll edit for code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`biography = Biography.where(user_id: current_user.id).eager_load(:lifestyle, :education, :location).first`

:)

Comment: Sorry, forgot `current_user.biography` doesn't return a scope! Try again now?

Comment: This is awesome, thanks.  Exactly what i've been looking for.
I'm not familiar with scopes hence why i don't understand why it didn't work with current_user.biography, but i'll read rails documentation for it. Thanks!!!

Comment: One caveat, I believe this will return an AR Relation, so `biography.lifestyle` will return an error. I think you'd need to do something like `biography[0].lifestyle` to access it. Someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Ah! duh, I missed the `first` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to me like a case for `as_json`. You could overwrite the default method in your `Biography` model to include the attributes you need for the biography, the associations you want to include, and the attributes for each of those associations (see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json). Then, to avoid n+1s, you could do something like:

```
biography = Biography.includes(:lifestyle, :education, :location).first

render json: biography.as_json
```

Comment: as_json seems like a really useful method, thanks.  But I'm not sure includes is reducing the number of queries, this will still need same number of queries as my original.

Comment: You are asking for information from 4 different tables, thus you will always get 4 queries from Rails. Even if you were to eager load all of this info into the variable, it still requires the queries.

Comment: I only see one sql query with kitkat's answer above.

Comment: Yes, I forgot that you can get one giant join query from that.

Comment: Also this will do the same thing as kitkat's answer if you add `.references(:lifestyle, :education, :location)` before the `.first` .

Comment: That's an excellent point! Your comment prompted me to look at the Rails source, and I found that `eager_load` and `includes.references` are two independent ways to force a `JOIN`: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb#L358. The more you know!

Comment: Nice!  Have you learned anything special about these two cases?